# When Filtering records in BreezeJs throwing an error

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am trying to filter the records from a table based on a column value using `BreejeJs`. Here is the below code

[image]

while filtering based on a column name it's throwing an error like below

> The left hand side of a binary predicate cannot be a literal expression, it must be a valid property or functional predicate expression: parentFolderGuid(column name).

Any help will be  Appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, copy and paste the code to your question body instead.

Comment: Is 'parentFolderGuid' the name of a property on an entity?  What does the `_getFolders` method do?

Comment: _getFolders Method is to retrieve all the folders from the database based on above filter of key and value